# App Terminating due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I am trying to display the values of an array on a table in landscape mode, however I get the following error and it crashes the app :

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringToIndex:]: Index 9223372036854775807 out of bounds; string length 10'**.

This is my code :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

     [super viewWillAppear:YES];
     NSLog(@"Orientation Current: %ld", (long)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]);

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    NSLog(@"Here found");
    [self forceToOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.completedSubscriptionsTableView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.completedSubscriptionsTableView layoutIfNeeded];
 }

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self.completedSubscriptionsTableView setNeedsLayout];
    [self.completedSubscriptionsTableView layoutIfNeeded];
 }




 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section {
   return [self.subscriberArray count];

 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    PaymentHistoryCellTableViewCell *paymentHistoryCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [paymentHistoryCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    PaymentHistory *currentPayment = [self.subscriberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Current Payment: %@", currentPayment);
    [paymentHistoryCell.lblTransactionNo setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@", [[self.subscriberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"]]];
    [paymentHistoryCell.lblAmount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@", [[self.subscriberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"address"]]];

  if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    [paymentHistoryCell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:232/255.0 green:232/255.0 blue:232/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
} else {
    [paymentHistoryCell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

    cell = paymentHistoryCell;
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell layoutSubviews];
    [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [cell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  int space = 0;
  UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40.0)];
  [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:210/255.0 green:210/255.0 blue:210/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
  CGFloat viewWidth = (self.view.frame.size.width / [self.headerItems count]);
  NSLog(@"viewWidth: %f", viewWidth);

for(int i = 0; i < [self.headerItems count]; i++) {
    UILabel *headerLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((space * i) +  (viewWidth * i), headerView.frame.origin.y, viewWidth, headerView.frame.size.height)];
    [headerLbl.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [headerLbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [headerLbl setText:[self.headerItems objectAtIndex:i]];
    [headerLbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0]];
    [headerLbl.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [headerView addSubview:headerLbl];
    }
    return headerView;
    }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 40.0;
   }

   #pragma mark - Orientation Methods
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
   }
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 40.0;
  }


 - (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
  }

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
  }


 - (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

   if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
     [self forceToOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
    }
   }

 - (void)forceToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{

    NSLog(@"Forcing orientation to %ld",(long)toInterfaceOrientation);
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
   [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft]
                            forKey:@"orientation"];
   }


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

  }

- (void)setCompletedInstallations:(NSMutableArray *)compleInstalltions {
   self.subscriberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"SubmittedAt" ascending:NO];
   self.subscriberArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:     [compleInstalltions sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]]];

    NSLog(@" These are the completed subscriptions -> %@",_subscriberArray);
    [self.completedSubscriptionsTableView reloadData];
  });
}
```

Comment: check your array , error says for ex-: your array have 10index but you tried to access 11th. Check if you have any such case.

Comment: Telling us on which line that is triggered might help.

Comment: the only time I access the array is numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRowAtIndexPath and setCompletedInstallations

Comment: Your shown code shouldn't produce the error. You "play" with string only with `cellForRow` and you use `withFormat:`, so not there. But clearly `[[self.subscriberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"zzz"]` that's usually bad habit of using `valueForKey:`, and you already got the `PaymentHistory`. Why not doing `[paymentHistoryCell.lblTransactionNo setText:[currentPayment Name]]` or something similar (or you can use the `valueForKey:` and not adding the "\t" effect on the custom cell instead?

Comment: Unrelated but do you know in detail what all the subsequent calls `setNeedsLayout` `layoutIfNeeded`, `layoutSubviews` etc. in `cellForRow` are doing or did you mean *don't harm, put'em all in*?  Some of the methods could be expensive when called in any cell.

Comment: I'm trying to update the table once I force the orientation of the view to landscape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`9223372036854775807` is the unsigned cast of `-1`, which is `NSNotFound`. Per the error message, you are calling `-[NSString substringToIndex:]` with the result of a search that didn't find what you were looking for.

This section of code is not shown, so look for anywhere where you think you can pull apart a string, but are not properly checking that you actually can. Try running with the debugger attached and it will tell you which line of your code raises the exception reported. You can work backwards from there.

Comment: in my code I have these two lines I didn't add, scheduledDate = [schedDate substringToIndex:rangeOfSubstring.location]; and completedDate = [complDate substringToIndex:rangeOfSubstringg.location];

Comment: If you inspect `rangeOfSubstring` — either `NSLog` it or put in a breakpoint — you should see that `rangeOfSubstring.location` is `-1`, which means that the method you called to calculate it could not find the thing you asked it to look for.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was clear as daylight and your suggestion pretty spot on. I found my bug and fixed it. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The index you are trying to use is not found, which leads to the crash. Check the value you are passing to method [NSString substringToIndex:]